# Is multiple variable comparision inline undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

I was telling a friend of mine (which is learning C) that he couldn't do multiple variables comparision at once:

```
int main(){
    int a[4];

    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3]);

    if(a[0] < a[1] < a[2] < a[3]){
        printf("OK!\n");

    }

    else{
        printf("I've told ya\n");

    }

}
```

So, to prove I was right I've coded the program above and then I've executed it with `1 2 3 4`. Surprisingly it printed `OK!`. And so I didn't know what to tell him, because I was sure it wasn't right.

Finally, is it or is it not undefined behavior?

Comment: No, do it by hand the way C does it.

Comment: Try it with negative numbers, like `-4 -3 -2 -1`.

Comment: It also breaks for `4 3 2 2`. Which prints `OK!`.

Comment: "I don't know what to tell him" You can quote gcc warning message for him: _comparisons like ‘X<=Y<=Z’ do not have their mathematical meaning_

Comment: This warning doesn't appear here...

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira If You won't explicitly enable compiler warnings in gcc, it _won't_ show most of them. Try again with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags enabled.

Comment: @Vinska Ah, thanks! Now I've seem them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's well-defined. It simply has different semantics to what you're expecting.

The expression is evaluated as follows:

```
if (((a[0] < a[1]) < a[2]) < a[3]) {
```

Each comparison produces a boolean (`0` or `1`) outcome.

The (boolean) result of `a[0] < a[1]` is compared to `a[2]`, and the (boolean) result of that comparison is compared to `a[3]`.

I am sure there are some legitimate use cases, but they are rare at best.

The correct way to express what you're trying to express is

```
if (a[0] < a[1] && a[1] < a[2] && a[2] < a[3]) {
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not undefined behavior, it just doesn't do what you think it does. It's equivalent to

```
(((a[0] < a[1]) < a[2]) < a[3])
```

`1` for true, `0` for false. So if a[0] is less than a[1], then it's comparing a[2] to 1, otherwise, to zero. And so on.

Answer (score 4):

It's not *undefined behavior*, it's *unexpected-to-you behavior*.

In C and C++ you cannot do math-like comparisons like that. You can compare two things at a time. So, if you want `a < b < c < d`, you must write:

```
if (a < b && b < c && c < d)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you brought C++ into the mix, you could very simply do

```
if ( std::is_sorted(a, a+4) )
    puts("OK!");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is defined behaviour, but doesn't do what you expect, so don't do that.

Your expression becomes:

```
((a[0] < a[1]) < a[2]) < a[3]
```

where each x < y is turned into either 1 or 0 - which means that it's ALWAYS true if a[3] is greater than 1, and possibly true if a[3] is greater than 0.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't undefined behavior, but it doesn't do what he thinks it does. < is left-to-right associative, so first `a[0] < a[1]` is evaluted, resulting in `true`. Then `true < a[2]` (equivalent to `1 < a[2]`) is evaluated, resulting in `true`. And so on. You only got the right result by coincidence. For example, "2 1 0 1" would also yield true. Use either

```
a[0] < a[1] && a[1] < a[2] && a[2] < a[3]
```

or more generally, if your array is long:

```
for(i=1,ok=1;i<n&&ok;i++)ok &= a[i-1] < a[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation of the < operator, when appearing like this, is well-defined. The code you have written is equivalent to:

```
bool x;

x = a[0] < a[1];

if(x == true)
{
  x = true < a[2]; 
}
else
{
  x = false < a[2]; 
}

if(x == true)
{
  x = true < a[3]; 
}
else
{
  x = false < a[3]; 
}

if(x == true)
{
  printf("OK!\n");
}
else
{
  printf("I've told ya\n");
}
```

true always evaluates to the integer 1, false to 0. As you can tell, this code makes no sense at all.